# Problem loading package

Tags: packages

I'm a new user and I'm trying to load a package in Mathematica 11.0.

I've copied the DisturbingFunction.m package to %appdata%\Mathematica\Applications but after this I can't load it. I've tried with

```
<< DisturbingFunction`
Get[DisturbingFunction`]
Needs[DisturbingFunction`]
```

but none of this results. In the first two I don't get any message, but in the last I get

```
Needs::nocont: Context DisturbingFunction` was not created when Needs was evaluated.
```

Can you figure any reason why is this happening? Thank you!

**Edit 1**

Following Kuba's suggestion, the first time I run `$Packages` I get

```
{"GetFEKernelInit`", "StreamingLoader`", \
"SymbolicMachineLearningLoader`", "IconizeLoader`", \
"HTTPHandlingLoader`", "CloudObjectLoader`", "ResourceLocator`", \
"PacletManager`", "System`", "Global`"}
```

After running Get

```
{"CURLInfo`", "CURLLink`Cookies`", "OAuthSigning`", "CURLLink`HTTP`", \
"CURLLink`", "QuantityUnits`", "GetFEKernelInit`", \
"StreamingLoader`", "SymbolicMachineLearningLoader`", \
"IconizeLoader`", "HTTPHandlingLoader`", "CloudObjectLoader`", \
"ResourceLocator`", "PacletManager`", "System`", "Global`"}
```

Comment: That error means that the context wasn't created but there is no error about `Get` failing to find the file. So probably the package has a non standard structure. Clear the kernel, run `$Packages` then ``Get @ "DisturbingFunction`"`` and `$Packages` again, what was added?

Answer (score 3):

When you look inside the `DisturbinFunction.m` file you see the call

```
BeginPackage["Perturbations`DisturbingFunction`",
  "Perturbations`Common`PerturbationsCommon`"]
```

This tells you that this file is part of a larger package `Pertubations`. Additionally, you see that it needs a second package `` Perturbations`Common`PerturbationsCommon` ``.

The easiest way is to ask the author for the complete package.